# how setup appearance animation to my listView in android?

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-studio, appearance

i try to add an `appearance animation` to my `ListView`. When I search on the internet i finally found this link to start. [ListView appearance demo](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/wiki/Appearance-Animations)

this is my `MainActivity` and `onCreateView`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);


    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");
    strings.add("");

    MyListAdapter mAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this, strings);
    SwingRightInAnimationAdapter swingRightInAnimationAdapter = new SwingRightInAnimationAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Assign the ListView to the AnimationAdapter and vice versa
    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    swingRightInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(myListView);
    myListView.setAdapter(swingRightInAnimationAdapter);
}
```

But when i launch this simple sample project an error rises with this content:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator[]

I download the jar lib and use it in build.gradle in `android studio`

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-core_3.1.0.jar')}
```

help me if it's possible
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the NineOldAndroids jar in your project to make this library work. You can download it here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/downloads

And as `Joel` stated in the comments you don't need to add the jars to your compile file since `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` takes care of that.

You can also do this without any jar files. Sync in android studio with an repository like this:

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
  compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-manipulation:3.1.0@aar'
}
```

You can check more dependencies to compile for this library on this page: https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Comment: Do you really need to the jars to your gradle file if you put them in the libs directory? Isn't that what `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` is for?

Comment: i download that lib (jar file) and add to my dependencies. but i have an Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: @Ashkan please be more specific. What kind of nullpointer exception? Did you include the NineOldAndroidAndroids jar? And did you remove `compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-core_3.1.0.jar')}` from your gradle build file?

Comment: no, i just remove the `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` line. how can i tell you about the kind of my error?

Comment: Do not remove compile `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']`. That is how your jar gets initialized. Please only remove `compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-core_3.1.0.jar')`.

Comment: i live in Iran, after your answer i check step by step and see i have to set proxy to my android studio to download the com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
tnx for your help

Answer (score 0):

You don't have nineOldAndroids jar in your project.

Download the jar files you need:
lib-core
lib-manipulation
lib-core-slh
Download the latest NineOldAndroids .jar file

Add the .jar files to your project's libs folder, or add them as external jars to your project's build path.

Please read the Readme of the github project